# Narrow a Joda-Time partial

Tags: java, jodatime

What's the best way to construct a partial from another partial which conains all the necessary fields (e.g. `YearMonth` from `LocalDate`? One way I can see is to convert to a full instant and back, that is

```
YearMonth ld2ym(LocalDate ld) {
    return new YearMonth(ld.toDateTime(DateTime.now()));
}
```

but it seems like a more efficient way should be possible.

Comment: Don't really get the `DateTime.now()` thing.
Isn't is easier just to do: 
`LocalDate ld = new LocalDate();
        YearMonth ym = new YearMonth(ld);`

Comment: @Kennet This is shorter, but will end up doing the same work, so far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, so your method wolud look like 
`YearMonth ld2ym(LocalDate ld) { 
    return new YearMonth(ld); 
}`
So why are you using `DateTime.now()`?

Comment: @Kennet Because this version makes the inefficiency more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

On the `YearMonth` class we can find this method which seems to give the appropriate solution:

```
/**
 * Parses a {@code YearMonth} from the specified string using a formatter.
 * 
 * @param str  the string to parse, not null
 * @param formatter  the formatter to use, not null
 * @since 2.0
 */
public static YearMonth parse(String str, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
    LocalDate date = formatter.parseLocalDate(str);
    return new YearMonth(date.getYear(), date.getMonthOfYear());
}
```